# Reading a string character by character into a function

Tags: c++

I am not sure if I am heading in the right direction. The function works. I thought the `for` loop would work too, but it isn't.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void bear(string word) {
    cout << "  (c).-.(c)  \n";
    cout << "   / ._. \\   \n";
    cout << " __\\( Y )/__ \n";
    cout << "(_.-/'-'\\-._)\n";
    cout << "   || " << word << " || \n";
    cout << " _.' `-' '._  \n";
    cout << "(.-./`-'\\.-.) \n";
    cout << " `-'     `-' \n";
}

int main()
{
    string word;
    cout << "Input a word: ";
    cin >> word;

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        cout << bear(word[i]);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you have to apply a loop for this case? Calling `cout << bear(word);` would work just fine?

Comment: What does it print?

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis I suspect that code [won't even compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f6256961de898f6).

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow! We would love to help, but it's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to achieve. Do you want the letters to appear one after the other, in an animation, on top of the same bear? Do you want many bears, each with its own letter? Please [edit] your question to make it clearer what you want to do.

Comment: [Check this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d78dffadbca56bd7) if it does what you want. _@Pblogetas_

Comment: You only need a single `cout` in `void bear(string word)`. Do you really want to print 1 bear for every character in word with one of it letters substituted where you have `word` in `bear()`? If so, change the parameter to `char` and use a range based `for` loop or use [std::basic_string::substr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) to pass the character as a substring of `word`.

Answer (score 0):

You have some mismatched data types.

First, `cout << bear(word[i]);` tells `cout` to output the return of `bear()`, but `bear()` is a void function!  It has no return.  You just want to say `bear(blah)` in the for loop because calling the function will do the `cout` calls inside the function itself.

Second, `word` is of type `string`. `bear()` expects an argument of type `string`.  You are not passing `word` but instead are passing `word[i]`.  The type of `word[i]` is a single `char`.

To fix this, it really depends on what you want the function to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


void bear(string word) {
    cout << "  (c).-.(c)  \n";
    cout << "   / ._. \\   \n";
    cout << " __\\( Y )/__ \n";
    cout << "(_.-/'-'\\-._)\n";
    cout << "   || " << word << " || \n";
    cout << " _.' `-' '._  \n";
    cout << "(.-./`-'\\.-.) \n";
    cout << " `-'     `-' \n";
}

int main()
{

    string word;
    cout << "Input a word: ";
    cin >> word;

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        bear(word.substr(i, 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The for loop does not work because your function bear is not returning anything.

In other words;

You are calling the bear function inside a std::out which means there needs to be some data, some value to output. But your bear function doesn't return anything. Your bear function is doing the output.

For your for loop to work, just remove the cout, and call the bear function like normal.

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` does not have a constructor that takes only a single `char` as input, so you can't pass `word[i]` to `bear()` the way you are.

Also, your `for` loop makes no sense at all.

Get rid of the loop, and pass the full `word` as-is to `bear()`.

Also, `bear()` does not have a return value that you can pass to `cout`, so you need to get rid of that code, too.

Try this:

```
int main()
{
    string word;
    cout << "Input a word: ";
    cin >> word;

    bear(word);
}
```